# Are calculated columns indexable and followup

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, indexing, formula, calculated-columns

Are calculated columns in SharePoint 2010 indexable? I have found no definitive answer either way but there seems to be some support for 'yes'.

A follow up question: how to problematically (in C# as opposed to XML) represent a formula for the column that contains strings?

Not sure which quotes should be double (`"`), single (`'`), or escaped (`/"` or `/'`) or something else.

Example:

```
myCalculatedColumn.Formula = "=IF([colA]='somestring', 'thenThisString', 'elseThisString')"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found:
Yes, calculated columns are indexable for SharePoint search (Note: haven't tried this personally though). It is also indexable for FAST search. The caveat in FAST is that the calculated columns get pulled back funny when using it as a search refiner.

i.e. Say the calculated columns has the string value "FooBar". When used as a search refiner in FAST, it shows up something like "string;#FooBar" or "string;%FooBar". Haven't found a way around this, even tried manipulating the XML that shows up for FAST search. (Note: `<customfilters MappingType="ValueMapping" ... />` fails in FAST search because of the ValueMapping.)

It has to do with how the calculated column value is stored, retrieved, and displayed in SharePoint. Likely an oversight of the unpolished integration process of FAST search into SharePoint.

No solution on the follow-up questions.